# Mean field approximation in BCS theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, many-body, wick-theorem

Bardeen, Cooper and Schrieffer's (BCS) theory describes spinful Fermions that mutually interact via an attractive contact interaction. The general Hamiltonian reads in second quantization 
$$H = \sum_{\sigma \in \{\uparrow, \downarrow\}} \int d\mathbf{r} \,
\psi_\sigma^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \left( -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m} - \mu \right) \psi_\sigma(\mathbf{r}) + 
V_0 \int d\mathbf{r} \, \psi_\uparrow^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \psi_\downarrow^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \psi_\downarrow(\mathbf{r}) \psi_\uparrow(\mathbf{r})$$
with the creation $\psi_\sigma^\dagger(\mathbf{r})$ and annihilation $\psi_\sigma(\mathbf{r})$ field operators, interaction strength $V_0 < 0$ and chemical potential $\mu$. This general ansatz is simplified using the mean-field approximation to obtain the BCS Hamiltonian.

$$H_{BCS} = \sum_{\sigma \in \{\uparrow, \downarrow\}} \int d\mathbf{r} \,
\psi_\sigma^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \left( -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m} - \tilde{\mu} \right) \psi_\sigma(\mathbf{r}) + 
\int d\mathbf{r} \, \left( \Delta \psi_\uparrow^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \psi_\downarrow^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) + \Delta \psi_\downarrow(\mathbf{r}) \psi_\uparrow(\mathbf{r}) \right)$$
with the pairing gap $\Delta = V_0 \langle \psi_\downarrow (\mathbf{r}) \psi_\uparrow (\mathbf{r}) \rangle$ and the redefined chemical potential $\tilde{\mu} = \mu - V_0 \langle \psi_\downarrow^\dagger (\mathbf{r}) \psi_\downarrow (\mathbf{r}) \rangle$. The parameters $\Delta$ and $\tilde{\mu}$ are spatially constant as we consider a homogeneous system.

Usually, the first step from the general ansatz towards the BCS Hamiltonian involves Wick's theorem. As I am not very familiar with Wick's theorem I have the following **questions**.

1. As I understand, [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) is useful to rewrite products of operators as for example $\psi_\uparrow^\dagger (\mathbf{r}) \psi_\downarrow^\dagger (\mathbf{r}) \psi_\downarrow (\mathbf{r}) \psi_\uparrow (\mathbf{r})$ in an exact way. However, how does it help us to apply the mean-field approximation? What are the intermediate steps of the following calculation? To improve readability the position vector $\mathbf{r}$ is omitted.

$$\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow \approx 
% 
% pairing fields
\langle \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow \rangle \, \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger + \langle \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \rangle \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow \\
% 
% hartree fields
+ \langle \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \rangle \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow + 
\langle \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \rangle \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \\ 
% 
% fock fields
- \langle \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \rangle \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow 
- \langle \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \rangle \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow$$

2. Is there an alternate way to apply the mean-field approximation without Wick's theorem? For example by using the idea of the theorem's proof or employing a similar technique as for the Ising model ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_field_theory#Ising_Model)). Below you find my unsuccessful attempts.

**"Ising model technique"**

The idea is to write the product $A B$ of operators with their mean values $\langle A \rangle$ and $\langle B \rangle$ and the deviations $\delta A = A - \langle A \rangle$ and $\delta B = B - \langle B \rangle$.

$$A B = \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle + 
\langle A \rangle \delta B + 
\langle B \rangle \delta A + 
\delta A \delta B$$

As the mean-field approximation assumes small fluctuations $\langle \delta A \delta B \rangle \ll \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$ we can neglect the term quadratic in the deviations. By inserting the definitions of $\delta A$ and $\delta B$ we get

$$A B \approx \langle A \rangle B + \langle B \rangle A - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle.$$

When we apply this approximation naively to the interaction term we identify $A = \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger$ and $B = \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow$ and obtain only the first two terms. The additional constant offset is not observable ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/226998/179978)). Another attempt was to rewrite the expression with the fermionic commutation relations as follows before approximating it.

$$\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow = 
% 
\frac{1}{3} (\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow + \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow + \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow) \\
% 
= \frac{1}{3} (\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow + \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow - \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow + \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow)$$
Besides the required terms there is a disturbing summand $\psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow$ and an overall factor of $1/3$. Another idea is based on the observation that in mean-field $A B \approx B A$.

$$\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow = 
% 
\frac{1}{6} \cdot 6 \cdot \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow \\
% 
= \frac{1}{6} ( [\psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger + \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow - \psi_\downarrow \psi_\downarrow^\dagger] + [\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow] \\
% 
+ [\psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow] + [\psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow] \\
% 
+ [- \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow + \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow] + [- \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow + \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow]) \\
% 
% 
= \frac{1}{6} (\psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger + \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow 
% 
+ \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow + \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \\
% 
- \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow - \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow
%
+ 2 \psi_\uparrow^\dagger \psi_\uparrow - \psi_\downarrow \psi_\downarrow^\dagger + \psi_\downarrow^\dagger \psi_\downarrow)
$$

Also here the disturbing terms consisting of two field operators do not vanish.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE. Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your comment. Now I enriched my question to make it hopefully clearer.

Comment: I appreciate any hint that clarifies Wick's theorem used to get the BCS mean-field hamiltonian. Please also let me know if something is unclear. Thanks!